# How to set the TabLayout Value from the child tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have created tablayout fragment for profile. this TabLayout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        layout="@layout/common_act" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/color5"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/medium">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutPic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_profile_pic"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_profile_pic"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_profile" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePic"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gap_medium"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="@string/first_name"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/veryDarkGrey"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/darkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal"
                        app:font="@{@string/font_roboto_bold}" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mobile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gap_small"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/veryDarkGrey"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/darkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal"
                        app:font="@{@string/font_roboto_bold}" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/type"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/mobile"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gap_small"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/veryDarkGrey"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/darkGrey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal"
                        app:font="@{@string/font_roboto_bold}" />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gap_small"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Complete your profile "
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/veryDarkGrey"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/darkGrey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal"
                    app:font="@{@string/font_roboto_bold}" />

                <com.xx.xx.ui.widget.SeekBarWithLabel
                    android:id="@+id/seekBarCustomer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:performanceProgress="20" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/color3"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent" />


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I have created 2 fragments for this 
as profile and workshop.

Then I created the Main Fragment like this

```
public class ProfileFragment extends BaseFragment {

private MyprofileFragBinding mBinding;

public static ProfileFragment newInstance() {
    return new ProfileFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.myprofile_frag, container, false);

    mBinding.tabs.setupWithViewPager(mBinding.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(mBinding.viewpager);
    mBinding.layout.navMenu.setOnClickListener(view -> openTradeDrawer());

    return mBinding.getRoot();

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ProfileViewFragment(), getString(R.string.profile_view));
    adapter.addFragment(new WorkShopFragment(), getString(R.string.workshop_profile));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Like wise I have created the layout and classes. 
here the profile image and textview added in the main tablayout

Inside the first child Fragment I am calling the API So, How can I set the image and details into the tablayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout xml, define your TabLayout and ViewPager like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Then define your adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public static final int LOGIN_INDEX = 0;
public static final int WORKSHOP_INDEX = 1;

private final Context mContext;
private final List<Fragment> mFragments;

public MyAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
    mFragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case LOGIN_INDEX:
            return mContext.getString(R.string.login);
        case WORKSHOP_INDEX:
            return mContext.getString(R.string.workshop);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("too many tabs");
    }
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}
```

Define an interface to be implemented by your ProfileFragment:

```
public interface Listener {
    void displayInformations(String firstName, String name, String mobileNumber);
}
```

Modify your `ProfileFragment` like this and make it implements the interface:

```
@Override
@Nullable
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    mViewBindings = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.myprofile_frag, container, false);

    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>(2);
    fragments.add(LoginFragment.newInstance());
    fragments.add(WorkshopFragment.newInstance());

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewBindings.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mViewBindings.tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewBindings.viewPager);

    return mViewBindings.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void displayInformations(String firstName, String name, String mobileNumber){
    // display the informations
}
```

Change your `LoginFragment` like this:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private Listener mListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Listener) {
        mListener = (Listener) context;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("the parent should implement Listener");
    }
}

public void setInformations(String firstName, String name, String mobileNumber) {
        mListener.displayInformations(firstName, name, mobileNumber);
    }

}
```

Comment: In my TabLayout with those images is it possible to create as scroll able layout ?

Comment: is it possible to add the scroll view for whole screen with image ?

Comment: Is it something like [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/scrolling-behavior-for-appbars-in-android-41aff9c5c468) you want to achieve?

Comment: no I want to add the scrollview for entire design 
Still Searching the solution.

Comment: Scanario is like, 

About images and details are from tablayout class 

then the images I have added the pager 
then adapter bind 2 fragment for this tablayout
now below the pending nnd Add new scrolling 
but I need to scrol with that top images